# Background image in the simulator but not in the app from the play store

Tags: android, background, simulator

I have strange problem: I uploaded my first Android app to the play store today and a friend of mine who uses the Samsung Galaxy Nexus ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus ) just downloaded it but on the main screen there does not appear the background image I set in the app. However, testing the app in the simulator (with same device simulated) works, i.e. the background image is shown properly and everything works as wished.

How is that possible? Is there an inconsistency between the simulator and the corresponding real device? Even if so, this would be extremely bad...

Comment: the simulator has never been a great way to test an app since it is just plain terrible. It is always recommended you just use a device to test on for problems such as this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to install the .apk, that you exported with your keystore and published on Google play on the simulator to verify. 
If the background image is still missing then you might double check the res/drawable folders to find your background image. Do clean the project as well.